# Remove extra spaces, trim ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Remove extra spaces from the beginning and at the end after sending via ajax

```
$(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        data = jQuery.trim(data); (DONT WORK)
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml"
        });
```

Comment: example
(" 1234456 ")
need: ("123456")

Comment: `trim()` will remove spaces at the extents of the serialised string - which there wont be any. Are you instead trying to remove spaces to the *values* within that serialised string?

Comment: `trim` works on string , but here `data` is not string

Comment: @abc in which case just trim on the server side before you work with the values. It's simpler, and you should be sanitising all received values anyway

Comment: @brk `data` is a string in this example

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Via php I cut off, but via jquery it is sent with spaces

Comment: @abc in which case you could manually build the data object/serialised string you send in the request, trimming spaces from each value as you go, but as I mentioned in my previous comment it's far easier to just deal with boundary spaces on the server side. You should also be sanitising all data received on the server regardless, so this is a step which needs taking anyway

Comment: @abc   just trim on the server side or try this :  data.replace(" ", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns a URL encoded string and `Jquery.trim` removes space from the entire string which doesn't make any change to values.

Use [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method which returns an array and do the update on values by iterating.

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray();    
data.forEach(o => o.value = jQuery.trim(o.value)); // or data.forEach(function(o){ o.value = jQuery.trim(o.value) });
```

---

For making single space you can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray();    
data.forEach(o => o.value = o.value.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! How to make only single spaces?

Comment: data.forEach(o => o.value = jQuery.trim(o.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ' '))); may be that?

Comment: does not replace from 2 spaces to 1

Comment: @abc : i thought you are talking about the space at starting and ending

Comment: Great! Thank you!